# Remove containers by image name

Tags: bash, docker, unix

I mistakenly created a bunch of containers which I now want to remove. I can list them with:

```
docker container ls -aq -f "ancestor=portainer/portainer"
```

How can I "pipe" these container IDs to `docker container rm`?

What doesn't work:

- `docker ls -aq -f "ancestor=portainer/portainer" | docker container rm`
- `docker container rm $(docker ls -aq -f "ancestor=portainer/portainer")`
- `` docker rm `docker ls -aq -f "ancestor=portainer/portainer"` ``

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
docker container ls -aq -f "ancestor=portainer/portainer" | xargs docker container rm
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems my mistake was running `docker ls` instead of `docker container ls`. I'll leave this question up as I was unable to find any such examples on the WWW.

```
docker container rm $(docker container ls -aq -f "ancestor=portainer/portainer")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
for c in `docker container ls -aq -f "ancestor=portainer/portainer"`; do
   docker container rm $c
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This will always exit with success error code 0 even if there are no containers to remove:

```
docker ps -aq -f "ancestor=fakeuser/my-image-name" | xargs -I CID docker rm -f CID
```

If you want to give informative output in the logs:

```
docker ps -aq -f "ancestor=fakeuser/my-image-name" | xargs -I CID docker rm -f CID | awk '{print "removed container " $1}'
```